# Where is the origin for the sbt error below?

Tags: sbt

The problem looks like below:

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7

    ==== local: tried

      /home/jiakui/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7!sbt.jar:

      /home/jiakui/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/jars/sbt.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7!sbt.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
```

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/ivys/ivy.xml

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.pom

Server access Error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.jar

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
    unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7: not found
    Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
      (see /home/jiakui/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
    Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.7
    + exit 1

Comment: It cannot find the version of sbt you are asking. Can you try changing sbt to 0.13.5? Also, can you get the sbt version you are using (call: `sbt sbtVersion`)?

Comment: yes, sbt 0.13.5 works!!! but sbt 0.13.8 and sbt 0.13.7 do not work. This looks pretty strange for me.

Comment: what is your scala version? `scala -version` to get the runtime version. In case you specify a different version in your build.sbt, send me that one as well.

Comment: Is this resolved? What did you do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround.

Run this at command line:

`sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure`

The issue seems to be related to this one: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/19 (at least for me).

It seem, as far as I understand, that this bug can get back at JDK9 =/